# Python 3.5.1 Import doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

I want to import a .py file that's in the same directory as the code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
directory
|-- bot.py
|-- commands.py
```

commands.py:

```
def init_commands(message):
   print(message)
```

bot.py:

```
import commands

commands.init_commands('test')
```

Comment: What is the error? Nothing happens?

Comment: Tell us what error are you getting.